# Meaning of a paragraph about causal effect

Tags: meaning-in-context

Author is talking about the causes of cognitive disorders (like dementia). This paragraph is about emotional causes. I think the example (bolded) is not related to the first sentence. The first sentence is saying that psychological disorders have some features that may  seem like organic disorder, but the example says that organic disorders (like hypothyroidism) have symptoms which are like depression (as a psychologic disorder). (And none of them are related to the **causal** effects of emotional factors on organic disorder). Am I right?

Many stress-related symptoms mimic organic disorders. For example, **depression can be a predominant symptom of hypothyroidism, Addison’s disease, and brain tumors.** The psychiatrist must consider these possibilities before deciding that the illness is due to emotional conflicts. In older persons, depression can have the appearance of dementia, with confusion, recent memory loss, and poor functioning. Treating the basic depression can completely relieve this pseudodementia.

Source: Richard W. Roukema. What every patient, family, friend, and caregiver needs to know about psychiatry.

Answer (score 1):

I think the paragraph is logical, and it makes sense to me.

The author first states that psychological disorders can have identical symptoms to organic disorders. The example he provides is ***depression***, which can be a ***predominant symptom*** of both psychological and organic disorders. He then states that depression is a symptom of ***hypothyroidism, Addison's disease, and brain tumors*** (organic disorders) as well as ***dementia*** (psychological disorder).

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thank you very much Ringo. Would you look at these statements please? 1.depression mimics A if when you are depressed I think you are A (and probably you are not A) (first sentence). 2. Depression is symptom of A if when you are A I think you are depressed (Example). 3. depression causes A if when you depressed you become A (the main point of paragraph).

Comment: @user52346 Sorry, there are too many errors in grammar and missing words in these sentences to understand what is being said. Can you create a new question?

Comment: I tried to show the ambiguity and inconsistency of the Roukema's sentences, by differentiating between three statement: 1.Depression mimics X, if when you are depressed I think you are X (and probably you are not X) (first sentence). 2. Depression is symptom of X, if when you are X I think you are depressed (Example). 3. Depression causes X, if when you are depressed you become A (the main point of paragraph).

Comment: I'll give a full size answer if you create a new question. It's not practical to try to answer something this complex in comments.